# Measurable in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space. For measurable functions $f,g: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ let $f \sim g$ if $f$ is almost everywhere equal to $g$.

Show that $\{x \in \Omega \space| \space f(x) \neq g(x) \}$ is measurable.

---

I found $\int_E f \space d \mu:=\int_E u \space d \mu \space + i \int_E v \space d \mu$ for $f= u+iv$ with $u,v: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ as a definition, and we say that $f$ is measurable if $u$ and $v$ are measurable but I don't really know how to proof this.

Comment: $f-g$ is measurable. Composing with $z \to |z|$ we see that $|f-g|$ is measurable. Hence $|f-g|^{-1}(\{0\})$ is measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write
$$
\{ x : f(x) \neq g(x) \} = \{ x : (\Re f)(x) \neq (\Re g)(x)\} \cup \{ x : (\Im f)(x) \neq (\Im g)(x)\}
$$
so that it suffices to assume that $f$ and $g$ are real-valued.  Then we can write
$$
\{x : f(x) \neq g(x)\} = \{x : f(x) < g(x) \} \cup \{x : f(x) > g(x) \} = \left( \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \{ x : f(x) < q \} \cap \{ x : g(x) > q \} \right) \cup \left( \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \{ x : f(x) > q \} \cap \{ x : g(x) < q \} \right).
$$
Thus we've expressed the desired set in terms of countable unions and intersections of measurable sets.